# detect a change in url of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an html page with iframe window in it. I want a variable to capture value as 0 when URL of iframe remains the same as initial and variable as 1 when there is a navigation within iframe.

Comment: Have you tried coding anything yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrame src change event detection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var clicked = 0;
$('iframe').load(function(){
        var iframe = $(this).contents();
        //notices if a tag is clicked within iframe
        iframe.find("a").click(function(){
               clicked = 1;
        });
});
```

Or you could mean something like this(?):

```
var clicked = 0;
$('iframe').load(function(){
        //store URL
        var src = $("a").attr('src');
        var iframe = $(this).contents();
        //notices if a tag is clicked within iframe
        iframe.find("a").click(function(){
               //has the URL changed?
               if(src != $(this).attr('src')){
                   clicked = 1;
               }else{
                   clicked = 0;
               }
        });
});
```

Final tested script with `.link` being the link inside the iframe:

```
var clicked = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').load(function(){
            var iframe = $(this).contents();
            var src = iframe.find(".link").attr('href');
            //notices if a tag is clicked within iframe
            iframe.find(".link").click(function(){
                   //has the URL changed?
                   if(src != iframe.find(".link").attr('href')){
                       clicked = 1;
                   }else{
                       clicked = 0;
                   }
                   console.log(clicked);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: $('iframe').load(function(){- would work when the iframe loads..but i want the script to run after there is some naviagtion happens...the main idea is i have an html page where i want to enable a button when any kind of naviagtion happens within iframe.

Comment: `iframe.find("a").click(function(){` notices if you click any `a` tag **after** the `iframe` loads. Have you tested my code?

Comment: this is the error i get at console-"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.bing.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."

Comment: yes @Maximilian i did test your code..above is the error i m facing.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22625988/2768038) is a good answer to what might be happening in your case