# JSFIDDLE "d3 is not defined" differences

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Why does this fiddle's results work http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/k74rs1fk/1/

and this one's doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/k74rs1fk/1/

A look at the latter's console says `d3 is not defined`?

Both examples have D3 3.0.4 onLoad.

Same behavior in both Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is logged in the console itself:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://fiddle.jshell.net/airwwwave/k74rs1fk/1/show/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: got it. if i change https to http on the latter, it works. thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it! Welcome :)

Comment: It's interesting. So, I've made a brand new fiddle, pasted in JS code, set D3 3.0.4 onLoad, the browser says `http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/x54709hx/` and now the Chrome console says `"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."` Seems like JSFIDDLE only works with D3 sometimes? What am I missing? Ha.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625764/changing-src-of-iframe-inside-iframe